# Lock row to specific cell in Excel

Tags: excel, locking, row, cell

I have B1:B501 column that includes P/N's. The column auto-sorted by array formula. If i add new item in my BOM, the B column automatically resorted (A-Z).
Each part have 100 cell for price. B1 part have C1, D1, E1...; B2 part have C2, D2, E2... for price that i get from suppliers.
The problem happens, when i add new part to my BOM. The B column automatically resorted, and a new part can enter in the middle of the B column. This mixes between rows (prices of Bx part can move to By part).
I need solution that lock the row to specific cell (C3, D3, E3 only for part B3).
Sorry for my English.

[THIS IS PIC OF EXAMPLE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3PZ0Dla6vqIcW5rSVBzUTJmTzg/view?usp=sharing)

The column B auto-sorted. In columns C,D,E,F,G... i enter prices of part.
Now example of problem. If i add to my BOM new part, for example MUVBTR000002, it will enter to column B between MUVBTR000001 (row 4) and MUVCAP000001 (row 5). I.e. MUVBTR000002 will take row 5 (because the column auto-sorted A-Z), after MUVBTR000001. And MUVCAP000001 will move to row 6.
The problem, that after the MUVCAP000001 will jump to row 6, i will lose his prices, because they stay in they place on row 5 (column C,D,E...). I.e MUVBTR000002 will get prices of MUVCAP000001.
I need that prices of MUVCAP000001 in columns C,D,E... will jump to row 6 with MUVCAP000001.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking .. can you provide some sample data and what you expect as results ??  Just a few rows should be sufficient.

Comment: Hello Shmuel & welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to improve your question. Here's a [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help. I tried to improve my question. Also, add a picture

Answer (score 0):

If column **B** alphabetizes another column by formula,, then you need a set of *Match()* formulas in column **C** to find the **row number** of the item in the original data.

Once you have the row number, yo can use *Index()* formulas to retrieve other items on that same row.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help. I tried to improve my question. Also, add a picture